# Frequency between couples of words

Tags: r

Having a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5), keywords = c("google, yahoo, air, cookie", "cookie, air", "air, cookie", "google", "yahoo, google"))
```

How is it possible to extract a table like

```
df_binary_exist <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5), google = c(1,0,0,1,1), yahoo = c(1,0,0,0,1), air = c(1,1,1,0,0), cookie = c(1,1,1,0,0))
df_binary_exist
  id google yahoo air cookie
1  1      1     1   1      1
2  2      0     0   1      1
3  3      0     0   1      1
4  4      1     0   0      0
5  5      1     1   0      0
```

and from this table find the most frequent couples?

```
df_frequency <- data.frame(couple = c("yahoo-google", "cookie-air"), freq = c(2,3))
df_frequency
        couple freq
1 yahoo-google    2
2   cookie-air    3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part can be achieved by using `separate_rows`, `count` and `spread`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- df %>% separate_rows(keywords)

df1 %>%
  dplyr::count(id, keywords) %>%
  spread(keywords, n, fill = 0)

#     id   air cookie google yahoo
#   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1      1      1     1
#2     2     1      1      0     0
#3     3     1      1      0     0
#4     4     0      0      1     0
#5     5     0      0      1     1
```

---

For second part I used a base R method where we first `split` `keywords` based on `id`, `paste` combination of every 2 elements and count their frequency using `table`.

```
data.frame(sort(table(unlist(sapply(split(df1$keywords, df1$id), function(x) 
   combn(sort(x), pmin(2, length(x)), paste, collapse = "-")))), decreasing = TRUE))

#           Var1 Freq
#1    air-cookie    3
#2  google-yahoo    2
#3    air-google    1
#4     air-yahoo    1
#5 cookie-google    1
#6  cookie-yahoo    1
#7        google    1
```

Comment: I totally agree but is their any special handle if a keyword has two part i.e. "amazon stock, google, yahoo" i.e. "amazon stock" the code separates amazon and stock separate and I would like to have it as one word. Is it possible?

Comment: @ElrMant yes, you can add a separator in `separate_rows`. `df %>% separate_rows(keywords, sep = ",")` so it separates into different rows only based on comma and nothing else. Here, in the example as every keyword had only one word so I did not explicitly added the `sep` argument.

Comment: Thank you. It works. But is there any special handle for the second frequency couple part?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "special handle". If you mean different way, I showed you one way and another is shown by tmfmnk.

Answer (score 2):

One `tidyverse` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(keywords = strsplit(keywords, ", ", fixed = TRUE)) %>%
 unnest() %>%
 full_join(df %>%
            mutate(keywords = strsplit(keywords, ", ", fixed = TRUE)) %>%
            unnest(), by = c("id" = "id")) %>%
 filter(keywords.x != keywords.y) %>%
 count(keywords.x, keywords.y) %>%
 transmute(keywords = paste(pmax(keywords.x, keywords.y), pmin(keywords.x, keywords.y), sep = "-"),
           n) %>%
 distinct(keywords, .keep_all = TRUE)

  keywords          n
  <chr>         <int>
1 cookie-air        3
2 google-air        1
3 yahoo-air         1
4 google-cookie     1
5 yahoo-cookie      1
6 yahoo-google      2
```

It, first, splits the "keywords" column on `,` and then performs a full join with itself. Second, it filters out the rows where the values are the same as the OP is interested in pairs of values. Third, it counts the number of occurrences of pairs. Finally, it creates an ordered variable of pairs and keeps only the distinct rows based on this variable.

Or the same using `separate_rows()`:

```
df %>%
 separate_rows(keywords) %>%
 full_join(df %>%
            separate_rows(keywords), by = c("id" = "id")) %>%
 filter(keywords.x != keywords.y) %>%
 count(keywords.x, keywords.y) %>%
 transmute(keywords = paste(pmax(keywords.x, keywords.y), pmin(keywords.x, keywords.y), sep = "-"),
           n) %>%
 distinct(keywords, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this easily with

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(df[1],  mtabulate(strsplit(as.character(df$keywords), ", ")))
#  id air cookie google yahoo
#1  1   1      1      1     1
#2  2   1      1      0     0
#3  3   1      1      0     0
#4  4   0      0      1     0
#5  5   0      0      1     1
```

Comment: and from this table how is it possible to extract the most frequent pairs?

Comment: @ElrMant  You can do `combn` of 2 pairs and select the pairs with the most frequent, paste their names